# mysql insert malfunction

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why this isn't working. It says "note added" but it doesn't actually add it to the database.

```
<?php

    $notetitle = $_POST['title'];
    $notebody = $_POST['body'];

if ($notetitle && $notebody){
mysql_query("insert into notes values
('$user_id', '', '$subject', '$notetitle', '$note_type' '$notebody')");

echo "Note \"" . $notetitle . "\" added.";
}
```

?>

Comment: Notice that once it gets into the if($notetitle...) it will always do the echo even if it hasn't been inserted.

Comment: Don't forget to protect yourself against mysql injections ( use mysql_real_escape_string() http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php ).

Answer (score 7):

You missed a comma:

```
('$user_id', '', '$subject', '$notetitle', '$note_type', '$notebody')");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your code. use the code below and check it. I have added something more to be sure about your data accuracy:

```
<?php

$notetitle = $_POST['title'];
$notebody = $_POST['body'];

if ($notetitle != '' && $notebody !='') {
    $myQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notes VALUES
                          ('$user_id', '', '$subject', '$notetitle',
                          '$note_type', '$notebody')");

   // verify your database query and then show the message below
   if (mysql_affected_rows()) {
      echo "Note \"" . $notetitle . "\" added.";
   }
}

?>
```

Pay attention that you forgot a **comma** before '$notebody' in your MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is not quite valid - you also have to add to it the **column names** which you want to set through `INSERT`:

```
mysql_query("insert into notes (id, smth, subject, ... etc) values
('$user_id', '', '$subject', '$notetitle', '$note_type', '$notebody')");
```

Comment: @s3v3n - you are right, but in my opinion **explicit is better than implicit**

Comment: yes, I agree with you that explicit is better. Just wanted to mention that you said "you also have to add", that would mean "mandatory" not "better" (even if it is). Anyway, I think we cleared out enough the things.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked if the insert worked and reported errors on failure then you'd know why it wasn't working....

```
if ($notetitle && $notebody){
      $qry="insert into notes values
           ('$user_id', '', '$subject', '$notetitle', '$note_type' '$notebody')";
      if (mysql_query($qry)) {
           echo "Note \"" . $notetitle . "\" added.";
      } else {
           print "Failed: $qry\n" . mysql_error();
      }
}
```

Not handling errors and exceptions is very bad programming. Not declaring your columns in an insert statement is *very* bad practice. Not using an explicit database handle is messy. Not commenting your code is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a comma between "'$note_type' '$notebody'",

In better way you should to write like this:=

```
    $notetitle = $_POST['title'];
    $notebody = $_POST['body'];

if ($notetitle && $notebody){
mysql_query("insert into notes 
set userid='$user_id',
subject = '$subject',
notetitle = '$notetitle',
note_type = '$note_type',
notebody = '$notebody' ");

}
```

Actually it will not conflict your column name and values. :)